# winapi - painting rich edit thin border

Tags: winapi

By default a rich edit control has a "3d" border. I draw a thin border around a rich edit control this way:

```
if (message == WM_NCPAINT)
{
    RECT rc;
    HDC  hdc;
    HPEN  pen;
    HBRUSH brush;
    HGDIOBJ oldP, oldB;
    POINT tl, br;

    ::GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
    hdc = ::GetDC(hWnd);
    tl.x = rc.left;
    tl.y = rc.top;
    br.x = rc.right;
    br.y = rc.bottom;
    ::ScreenToClient(hWnd, &tl);
    ::ScreenToClient(hWnd, &br);
    pen = ::CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    brush = (HBRUSH) ::GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
    oldP = ::SelectObject(hdc, pen);
    oldB = ::SelectObject(hdc, brush);
    ::Rectangle(hdc, tl.x, tl.y, br.x, br.y);
    ::SelectObject(hdc, oldP);
    ::SelectObject(hdc, oldB);
    ::DeleteObject(pen);
    ::ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

    return 0;
}
```

The border looks fine but the area under the old border is not redrawn. It looks like I have to redraw to whole content of the rich edit control. After that a text shouldn't be a litte bit cut from the bottom. [Here](https://ibb.co/VjCRJKy) you can see what I mean (the second rich edit control has custom border). How to achieve it ?

Comment: If you're drawing a thinner border than the control says it has then you need to handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` and provide the proper dimensions to the OS.

Comment: I only get WM_NCCALCSIZE event for the main window. WM_NCCALCSIZE for an edit control is not sent to the main window events procedure and edit control events procedure.

Comment: Neither is `WM_NCPAINT`, presumably you're subclassing the control to handle that, so handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` the same way.

Comment: In the sublclass procedure I get only WM_NCPAINT, please see below answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GetDC` returns DC for client area. In this case you need `GetWindowDC` for the whole richedit window.

Either way, overriding border color in edit and rich-edit can be difficult, because you also have to handle scrollbar painting in `WM_NCPAINT`

Assuming you don't need vertical and/or horizontal scrollbar, use `GetWindowDC` as follows:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK RichEditProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp,
    UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR)
{
    static int border_thickness = 1;
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    {
        HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        rc.right += 2 * border_thickness + 1;
        rc.bottom += 2 * border_thickness + 1;

        HBRUSH hbrush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
        HPEN hpen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2 * border_thickness, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        HBRUSH oldbrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, hbrush);
        HPEN oldpen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hpen);
        Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
        SelectObject(hdc, oldpen);
        SelectObject(hdc, oldbrush);
        DeleteObject(hpen);
        DeleteObject(hbrush);

        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if(lp)
        {
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* sz = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*)lp;
            InflateRect(&sz->rgrc[0], -border_thickness, -border_thickness);
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, RichEditProc, 0);
        break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

By default, `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is not called in subclass procedure, you have to call SetWindowPos with `SWP_FRAMECHANGED`

```
HWND hrichedit = CreateWindowEx(...);
SetWindowSubclass(hrichedit, RichEditProc, 0, 0);
SetWindowPos(hrichedit, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

If you do need horizontal/vertical scrollbar, you might consider using a borderless richedit, then paint around the rich control in parent window's `WM_PAINT` procedure.

Comment: I have tested your answer, here is result: https://ibb.co/9TsYv95 It doesn't look correct.

Comment: Your attempt is clear missing call to `SetWindowPos(hrichedit, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED)` which I wrote.

Comment: SetWindowPos is called.

Comment: Your picture shows that the borders have not changed, `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is not received, therefore `SetWindowPos(... SWP_FRAMECHANGED)` was not called, or was not called in the right order as suggested.